# Error handling in useLazyQuery hook of RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Following is my implementation of the [useLazyQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) hook:

```
const [trigger,
        { 
    loading: prodLoading,
    error: prodError, 
    data: prodData 
    }
  ] = prodApi.endpoints.getAllProducts.useLazyQuery();
```

where the `result` parameter is de-structured into `prodLoading`, `prodError`, `prodData` respectively.
When the right parameters are passed to the query, the fetched products can be accessed through the `prodData`, but on error nothing is accessed through `prodError`, which brings me to my question, how do we handle errors in the `useLazyQuery` hook?

Is there any way to get parameters like `isLoading`, `error` we use in the [useQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery) hook?

```
const {data, error, isLoading, isSuccess} = useGetAllProductsQuery('', {skip,});
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually have an error? have you checked your network devtools and your redux devtools? Also, how are you checking for the error? On next render or within the callback tag called `trigger`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, it is exactly the same as the common `useQuery`'s interface.
Only one thing worries - seems like you are reading unexisting `loading` filed, which expected to be `isLoading`. Besides that, it's straightforward:

```
const [trigger, { isLoading, isError, data, error } ] = prodApi.endpoints.getAllProducts.useLazyQuery();
```

or

```
const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = await trigger();
```

Will be great if you'll log `error` with `isError` to the console to check if is actually an error occurred.